# Can not get count from database for two days ago

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code which i am using on another area of my website, basically it counts the rows of data in a database, now it works fine.

Now i want to do another count on another database however this time  the  date column is date time format, and the query doesn't seem to work.

Below is the piece of code i use to get the day from two days ago

```
$day_ago2 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d") - 1, date("Y")));
```

And below is the mysql code,

```
 SELECT * FROM page_views WHERE date='$day_ago2' and  member ='$site_id'
```

ANy help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF()` function

```
SELECT * FROM page_views WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) = -2 and  member ='$site_id'
```

Comment: Sorry just no result, i echoed the result and it just came back 0

Comment: change = 2 to = -2 and try again, and be sure that there is at least one 2 days old data on table

Answer (score 0):

Try not to create MySQL fields named after mysql functions/operators (like "date" or "where").

If you really want to use date function on the PHP side, for whatever reason, this is a more readable form:

```
// strtotime can take neat english input
$day_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 day") );
```

You'd of course do:

```
SELECT * FROM page_views WHERE date(`date`)='$day_ago' and  member ='$site_id'
```

Edit:

If taking input from a webpage, please make sure to sanitize all your input fields. Day_ago is safe because strtotime() with user input will in worse case give you a 0. However, make sure $site_id is safe. For example, issue this before the query:

`$site_id = intval( $_GET['site_id'] );`

or

`$site_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['site_id'] );`